# rails Net::FTP mkdir tree directory dont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ftp, tree, directory, mkdir

I have a FTP in Azure. I want to create a tree directory. Example i have this directory,

> /init/pages/

. I want to create 2 levels of subdirectories  in "pages/".  I send the command `ftp.mkdir("/init/pages/default/home")`. 
This throws an exception, because "pages" directory dont exist. This way I need to create "pages/" before the command to create "home/".
It is possible to create two directories in the same command ?

Im using Net::FTP, rails 4.2.6, ruby 2.2.0.

Thanks

Comment: never use azure but `mkdir  -p '/init/pages/'` works fine in linux.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's `NET::FTP` lib internally send raw `MKD` FTP command. Some ftp servers will create all folders in your path, but most don't.

```
def mkdir(dirname)
  resp = sendcmd("MKD #{dirname}")
  return parse257(resp)
end
```

So, you would have to create each folder on your own.